# How can I send my NFT (ERC721) Token (minted on ContractA) to another Smartcontract (ContractB) so that it is allowed to transfer it?

Tags: tokens, erc-721, erc-20-approve

I try to send my NFT token#300, which is an ERC721 token, minted on ContractA, to antoher ContractB, so that ContractB is now the owner of this Token#300 - so that the ContractB is now allowed to transfer this NFT to any other address it wants.

Is that possible? I know there exists also the approve() method, in which direction should I do my research to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally possible. If you are the NFT owner (ContractA would return your address for call `ownerOf` and your NFT id) you could simply call `safeTransferFrom` (where `from` address would be yours).

If you are not the owner, you need to be approved to transfer the NFT first by the owner.

Or if you just need to enable ContractB to move the NFT, you can simply approve it and then you can save one transaction (and gas). In this case, the NFT will stay yours, but ContractB would be able to send it to somebody else at any time.

Comment: wow that is exactly what I want. Ok now I need some tutorials how to implement this. Any resources?

Comment: You are looking for tutorials about implementing ContractA or how to call contracts to transfer your NFT?

Comment: About the part of the approve a ERC721 token, so it can be spend to any other wallet address. My Goal is actually an exchange. You send your NFT token to ContactB and it keeps it (or send it to another wallet) and instead mints for you a new Token.

Comment: I would use existing ERC721 implementation by open zeppelin as my super contract: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/tree/master/contracts/token/ERC721 and implement custom function to receive arbitrary NFT and send newly minted token to sender.

Comment: @Suisse if you find the answer as the one to your question, I would appreciate if you mark it as accepted :)